# How do I JOIN many-to-many tables using NotORM

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relational-database, notorm

I'm learning NotORM to produce a simple system for school. I want to be able to award 'Pledges' to 'students'. Here is my data structure:

My tables:

**students**

- -studentid (PK)
  -firstname
  -surname
  -dateofbirth
  -vmg
  -yeargroup

**link**

- -linkid (PK)
  -studentid (FK)
  -pledgeid (FK)
  -timeofaward

**pledges**

- -pledgeid (PK)
  -pledgename
  -pledgeinfo

The code from a great NotORM tutorial (http://www.sitepoint.com/database-interaction-made-easy-with-notorm/) says that I should do this:

```
<?php
foreach ($books as $book) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $book["title"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $book["author"] . "</td>";
// book_category table joins book and category
$categories = array();
foreach ($book->book_category() as $book_category) {
    $categories[] = $book_category->category["category"];
}
echo "<td>" . join(", ", $categories) . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

1. Is my data structure correct for using NotORM
2. How do I translate the example so that it shows the students and which awards have been awarded to them. - I feel like I have tried every variation of that code and still can't get it to work.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your 3 student/pledge table definitions and some queries and output that worked (including selecting all of each table) and something that didn't output what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to your problem: starting from the Relation-Table (here Link) and relaying on NotORM to join the other tables.

See how simple the code may be:

```
$db->link("pledge.name", $someName)->select("student.firstname, student.lastname");
```